# How to get data in descending order from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

i have tried this code

```
let newRef = Database.database().reference().root.child("recentlocations").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.id)
```

but its return data in ascending order and i want to get data in reverse order means in descending order. So what i have to do for that purpose?

Comment: If you are getting data in array than you can reverse array using `array.reversed()` function

Comment: i tried that one already but i don't want reverse array, i want get array in descending order from firebase

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59887724/firebase-both-query-by-ascending-descending-order

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314374, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38757248, and, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45154126, and probably more from this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+query+descending