# How to sort firebase order to Ascending using querySnapshot in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I am new in swift and I am working with firebase. I am getting the data but not in the correct order. I want to sort it into ascending order.
My code is like this

```
 func getBuzz(){
           db.collection("tablename").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
               if let err = err {
                   print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
               } else {
                   guard let docs = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                   return
               }
               print(docs)

               for document in docs {
                self.arrdescriptionbuzz.append(document["description"] as Any)
                self.arrimagebuzz.append(document["image"] as Any)
                self.arrnumericdigitbuzz.append(document["numeric_digit"] as Any)
                self.arrtitlebuzz.append(document["title"] as Any)
                self.arrlinkbuzz.append(document["link"] as Any)

               }
                for (index, element) in self.arrimagebuzz.enumerated() {
                    print("get Index \(index): getString \(element)")
                        let url = NSURL(string:element as! String)
                        if !(url?.absoluteString == "") {
                            let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check
                            if !(data?.isEmpty ?? true){
                                self.arrimagenewbuzz.append(UIImage(data: data! as Data) ?? UIImage (named: "Default.jpeg")!)
                            }else{
                                self.arrimagenewbuzz.append(UIImage (named: "Default.jpeg")!)
                            }
                        }

                }


                print("Data = ", self.arrimagenewbuzz.count)
                print("Image = ",self.arrimagebuzz.count)
                print("Title = ",self.arrtitlebuzz.count)
                print("Description = ",self.arrdescriptionbuzz.count)


                self.BuzzCollectionView.reloadData()
           }
       }
    }
```

I want to filter it according to document like as in the image there is 10 after 1 and I am getting the same data in swift. But I want to sort document so i will receive 1,2,3...
[image]

How can I sort it in swift. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The title of your question says 'sort' and then body of your question says 'filter' so that's confusing. Also, you've not specified any kind of sorting to Firestore, if you want the data sorted by the server (recommended) you need to sort it. See [Order and limit data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) and you should define field within each document to sort by. Lastly, the problem you're having is you are sorting a bunch of strings, so 1, 10, 11... 2, 20, 21... is a string sort order. You need to use numbers and sort numerically.

Comment: Also, it's usually a bad idea to have documents with id's like that. Let Firestore create the id's for you... or.... you can use an array but that's can be trouble as well.

Comment: @Jay I just want to sort docs into ascending order.

Comment: Ascending by what? The title? the numeric_digit? Which field do you want to sort by? Do you want to sort it on the server or in your code? Sorting in code can be challenging as if it's a large amount of data, it can overwhelm the device. DocumenId's are strings so that's not going to work - you need to change how you store your documents and not try to use integers for documentIds (as they MUST be strings, and therefore not sortable)

Comment: @Jay I want to sort it in code and by Orderdby field. Can sort is possible in firebase server side. If yes then how

Comment: Is Orderedby a string or integer?

Comment: @Jay it is number. If you want to change me it into string I can

Comment: Sorting is covered in the Firestore documentation and there are examples you can follow. See the link in my first comment and try to follow the guide to let firebase do the sort. It will make your code MUCH shorter. Once you've tried it, if you get stuck with Firebase sorting, let us know and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay How can I do it in my code.

Comment: SO Isn't a code writing service. Please review the steps in the guide and make an attempt to write the code to sort your data. When you get stuck with that code, post a question about it and we can take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `sort` method on collections?
e.g.:

```swift
docs.sorted { $0["some_value"] as! Int > $1["some_value"] as! Int }
```

Comment: By the order of which value/property?

Comment: By using this Add document id

Comment: so in `for document in docs...` how do you access the document id inside the for loop? What is the property name? Like `document["id"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use `filter` method? Adding the method in your db reference, will help you get the data sorted without sorting from front-end side of iOS

Depends which Database you're using for Firebase

Realtime DB: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data
Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: I recommend add field `sort_id` in every document (because the indexing in firestore ain't like usual database), then use that sort (that tapering triple bar icon in your collection) to get your sort result, u will get that sort code snippets at the bottom of that popup menu, apply that into your database reference to get sorted.

Exp. Item 01 (sort_id=0), Item 2 (sort_id=1) etc.

Comment: I added one parameter as OrderBy. But how can i Filter using it?

Comment: db.collection("tablename").orderBy("sort_id", "asc")

Comment: It would help to show a code example instead of just links back to documentation.  Links can break and change.

Comment: @SCKim Value of type 'CollectionReference' has no member 'orderBy'